# PostgreSQL: how to use NOT IN without WHERE?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries:

```
select * from  tableA
```

and

```
select a,b from tableA
group by a,b
```

the first query returns `2101 rows`
the second query returns `2100 rows`

I want to know which row is in the first but not in the second. It should be simple with `NOT IN`, but I can't find the correct syntax as `NOT IN` should be in `WHERE` statement. but I don't have a `WHERE` statement in my case.

Comment: What result do you get from the query `select count(*) from tableA` ?

Comment: It means that there is one duplicate row only based on the columns a and b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are N ways to do that and one of the simplest should be to find the rows that have a count > 1 when grouped on a,b.

```
select a,b from tableA
group by a,b
having count(*) > 1
```

Here is a sample:

```
with tableA as 
( 
   select * from (values 
     (1,1,1), 
     (1,1,1), 
     (1,2,1)
     ) as t(a,b,c)
)

select a, b from tableA
group by a, b
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: The `select * from` is unnecessary inside the CTE. You can use the `values` clause directly: `with tableA (a,b,c) as ( values (1,1,1), ...) ...`

Comment: Yeah, you can write the same thing in N ways:)

Comment: Yes, but you shouldn't use the most complicate one ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can get duplicates this way:

```
select a,b from tableA
group by a,b having count(1) > 1
```

Comment: Double check your query.